# PHP - Append db ID to variables

Tags: php, mysql

**What I need to make happen:** 
I am populating divs with data from mySQL based on the item ID. I need to create variables to be called into the divs such as $tip_ + $id which results in:

```
$tooltip_1
$tooltip_2
$tooltip_3
```

**What I have done so far:**

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM top_tips WHERE type =  "aw"';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $tip_ID = $row[0];
    $tip_text = $row[2];
    $tip_link = $row[3];

    $tooltip = "<div class='tooltip-close'><a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>" .$tip_text . " <a href='" .$tip_link . "'>read more ...</a>";

    echo $tooltip;
}
```

**Where I am stuck:** 
What is the most efficient way to output $tooltip + $tip_id so the variables can be called into the respective divs?

Comment: Any time you find yourself creating variables like that, you should be using an array instead.

Answer (score 2):

You would do it like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $tip_ID = $row[0];
    $tip_text = $row[2];
    $tip_link = $row[3];

    $tooltip = "tooltip_{$tip_ID}";

    $$tooltip = "<div class='tooltip-close'><a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>" .$tip_text . " <a href='" .$tip_link . "'>read more ...</a>";

    echo "tooltip_{$tip_ID}";
}
```

That will give you variables such as $tooltip_1, $tooltip_2 and so on. That said, I recommend you use an Array for this.

Answer (score 1):

**Added For foreach for your Code..**

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM top_tips WHERE type =  "aw"';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while ($results = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    foreach($results as $row){
    $tip_ID = $row[0];
    $tip_text = $row[2];
    $tip_link = $row[3];

    $tooltip = "<div class='tooltip-close'><a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>" .$tip_text . " <a href='" .$tip_link . "'>read more ...</a>";

    echo $tooltip;
    }
}  
?>
```

Hope you need this solution.. im confused in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of $tooltips like so:

```
$tooltip[] = "<div class='tooltip-close'><a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>" .$tip_text . " <a href='" .$tip_link . "'>read more ...</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you care about efficiency and how to concatenate your `$tooltip_` and `$tip_ID`. First about efficiency, I always learn : **When you are fetching results through a loop, never creates variables. Always outside !**

In your case, you could create it like this before fetching the results :

```
<?php
$tooltip_array = array(); //Future array containing your $tooltip_1, $tooltip_2...
$query = 'SELECT * FROM top_tips WHERE type =  "aw"';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Then, in your loop you can push each tooltip onto your array like this :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
array_push($tooltip_array,"<div class='tooltip-close'><a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>" .$row[2] . " <a href='" . $row[3] . "'>read more ...</a>");
}
```

Finally you can echo this out with a foreach loop :

```
// Iterating through the values
foreach($tooltip_array as $value)
{
  echo $value;
}
```

Comment: inside of the foreach, how do I append the db ID to the variable? So I can access via $tooltip_1 etc

Comment: @johanna you wouldn't. The foreach loop allows you access each item in the array which hold each of your tooltips without having to have a variable for each one. If you need that, you need to add another element in each $tooltip_array item.

Comment: So pull the ID into the tooltip array as it's being built. The select the item from the array like $array[id][value] ?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post the working solution I ended up using for anyone reading this thread.

```
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM tool_tips WHERE tip_type = "aw"';
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
              $tooltip_array[$row[0]] = "<div class='tooltip-close'><a 
        href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>" .$row[2]. "<a href='" .$row[3]. "'>read more ...</a>";
        }
```

Then I call the individual tooltips like:

```
<?php echo $tooltip_array[12];?>
```